# How to use HttpRequest Class in a Yii Application

Tags: php, http, yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP HTTP-Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565451/php-http-request)

I want to use a PHP Core class in my  Yii Application. However, Yii automatically tries to import the class name as a file.

How do I use a PHP core class in Yii WITHOUT it trying to import a file?

EDIT: (Add code)

```
$r = new HttpRequest('http://example.com/feed.rss', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$r->setOptions(array('lastmodified' => filemtime('local.rss')));
$r->addQueryData(array('category' => 3));
try {
    $r->send();
    if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
        file_put_contents('local.rss', $r->getResponseBody());
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

Comment: There, I edited the question to add my code. Sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you run into an error, you should as well show the error message and better describe what happens. *"Yii automatically tries to import the class name as a file"* for example is not clear to me what it means. Might be me, but error messages are helpful, often.

Answer (score 0):

HttpRequest is not installed/enabled by default PHP installation. You need to install it.

Because it doesn't exists Yii tries to autoload from its known folders.