# How to exec external script

Tags: php, exec, external

Hello i want to ask how to exec external php script with `exec()` which is not located on my website
Does it work like this ?

```
exec("php http://site.com/executor.php?something=1&something2=A");
```

Comment: You **cannot** execute PHP on site you do not own. This question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565451/php-http-request

Comment: So i need to use HttpRequest?

Comment: Yes, you just need to send HTTP request

Answer (score 1):

No, because when using HTTP the remote server sends the *result* of the PHP script. The command doesn't support URLs just because of that. If you want to execute the *code* on the remote server you need to have access to the PHP file itself. If you just need the *result*, you can use e.g.

```
readfile("http://site.com/executor.php?something=1&something2=A")
```

or other ways to read from URLs (`fopen` and `fread`, `file_get_contents`, `file`...).