# undefined class constant METH_GET

Tags: php, httprequest

I have the following php code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
require_once 'HttpRequest.php';
$r = new HttpRequest("http://192.168.0.223:8080/dsrmap/msfleet.php", HttpRequest::METH_GET);
//$r_test = new HttpRequest("http://192.168.0.223:8080/dsrmap/msfleet-test.php", HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$r_test = new HttpRequest("http://192.168.0.223:8080/dsrmap/msfleet-dev.php", HttpRequest::METH_GET);
```

when I run this I get the message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'METH_GET' in /home/jsnyder/jsonmaker/map.php 

Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'METH_GET' in /home/jsnyder/jsonmaker/map.php
```

do you know what is causing this error.  I had to manually download a HttpRequest and put it in the directory that this program is in because I got the error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HttpRequest' not found in /home/jsnyder/jsonmaker/map.php
```

Based on the information I gave can you help me resolve this issue?  How am I supposed to install HttpRequest so I can use this in my code?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP HTTP-Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565451/php-http-request)

Comment: Is the pecl extension php_http installed?

Answer (score 0):

> had to manually download a HttpRequest and put it in the directory that this program is in because I got the error:

That sounds to me like you downloaded a random class with the same name somewhere and crossed your fingers it would work.

It's likely you simply have the picked the wrong library.