# PHP Curl converted to command line equalivalent

Tags: php, curl

I'm doing a PHP curl request,
Something like this (tho the specifics are not important) :

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => $aServerEndPoint,
        CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => yadda yadda, this is pseudo code
    ));


    $resp = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
```

I would like to see what the command line equivalent of this would be; Is there a PHP curl command I can use to show me that?

Comment: Downvote?!
So unhelpful!
Who are you and why did you downvote?  Did you not understand the question?  What is the problem?

Comment: do you mean a function that compiles everything you've made up in PHP curl and converts it into a single line curl command? i don't think such function exists, you could try to do it by hand though

Comment: Up-voting since this is a valid question.

Comment: @Ghost - yes, that is exactly what I am after.